# Changed URL and website name of site in Wordpress, can't access site

Tags: wordpress

I was working on a WordPress website using localhost and MAMP. I tried to change the name of the website to use port 80 instead of 8888 by changing `http//localhost:8888/wordpress/` to `http//localhost:80/wordpress/`

This causes me to be unable to access the dashboard of the website.

I tried adding code to wp-config.php, but it did not seem to work.

I accessed **phpMyAdmin** and changed **siteurl** and **home** back to the original url, but this also did not work.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I can now access the dashboard, but not the website itself.

Comment: As per your content Need http// to http://.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a ubuntu server the first step I would take is to check if port 80 is allowing a connection using the following command

```
`sudo ufw status`
```

if you do not see port 80 listed use the command 
`sudo ufw allow 80`

in the future I would redirect the port internally using

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8888`

Comment: I am able to access the dashboard now, but I can't access the website itself.  I would like to revert to 8888 as it originally was to avoid this confusion. Do you have any idea of why I can't access the site?